# How to add custom validator for angular form if input is not required?

Tags: angular

I have 2 inputs

- email
- message

*customValidator* is some function.

Email is required and looks like that

```
`email: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.email,
    Validators.required,
    this.customValidator
  ]),`
```

Message is not required and can be completely empty, but I need add the same customValidator to it.

```
`message: new FormControl('', [])`
```

When I adding only customValidator

```
`email: new FormControl('', [
    this.customValidator
  ]),`
```

it causes error
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j74co.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing suggests that there is no overload of the FormControl constructor that accepts an array of validators as the second argument.

To add a custom validator to the message FormControl without any additional validators, you can use the setValidators method after creating the FormControl:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
  email: FormControl;
  message: FormControl;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.email = new FormControl('', [
      Validators.email,
      Validators.required,
      this.customValidator
    ]);

    this.message = new FormControl('', []);
    this.message.setValidators(this.customValidator);
  }

  customValidator(control: FormControl) {
    // Add your custom validation logic here
    return null; // Return null if the validation passes, or an object if it fails
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.email.valid && this.message.valid) {
      // Perform form submission logic
    } else {
      // Handle form validation errors
    }
  }
}
```